# Using bTouch to bind to the ArcGIS iOS SDK

Tags: binding, xamarin.ios, arcgis

I apologize for such a long message in advance, but I'm trying for detail here...

I'm working on using bTouch to create a compiled dll for referencing the ArcGIS iOS SDK. 
When running bTouch using :

```
/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/btouch libArcGIS.cs
```

it returns the following error

```
/tmp/fp2ivuh8.3gj/IncidentReportApp/AGSMutablePolygon.g.cs(39,31): 
    error CS0102: The type `IncidentReportApp.AGSMutablePolygon'  
    already contains a definition for `selAddPointToRing'
/tmp/fp2ivuh8.3gj/IncidentReportApp/AGSMutablePolygon.g.cs(38,31):  
    (Location of the symbol related to previous error)
/tmp/fp2ivuh8.3gj/IncidentReportApp/AGSMutablePolyline.g.cs(39,31): error CS0102:  
    The type `IncidentReportApp.AGSMutablePolyline' 
     already contains a definition for `selAddPointToPath'
/tmp/fp2ivuh8.3gj/IncidentReportApp/AGSMutablePolyline.g.cs(38,31):  
    (Location of the symbol related to previous error)
Compilation failed: 2 error(s), 0 warnings
```

I checked my cs class and neither type is referenced\invoked. I'd like to understand why this message is occuring.

I have tried to use the instructions (and downloaded) code by Al Pascual at [How to use the ArcGIS iPhone SDK with MonoTouch](http://weblogs.asp.net/albertpascual/archive/2010/08/02/how-to-use-the-arcgis-iphone-sdk-with-monotouch.aspx) to call the Map View, but when attempting to launch the view with the code causes a crash. When I try to debug, it locks up when adding a mapping layer. I tested this with the MKMapView, but didn't experience the same behavior.

Comment: In the Al Pascual link you gave, there is a link to a working solution you could use? - http://www.arcgis.com/sharing/content/items/6fd36c9605ec4698a4323b09a38f6645/data?token=aShJbxTN_HoHepZyGUsUTUnvczEZ7Ocui60dyzfj4XFspIy36A5DitS_J8fjo-mi

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the solution I provide with the correct bindings

Comment: Al, I tried that, but all that happened in the simulator is that the app crashed. I tried both the sim version and the non-sim version of the .dlls. I'm using ArcGIS' most current version of the mapping api; would that work with the solution you have posted? (I assume you meant the one at the ArcGIS site.)

Comment: Al, I have been trying your source code from the ArcGIS site, and it won't build. It says "mtouch failed with no output" when I attempt a build or rebuild. I also tried removing (but not deleting) the binding classes and the issue was still the same. I'm not saying it doesn't work at all, just that it won't build for me.

Comment: The bindings you have available are outdated and a small subset of the actual library.

Answer (score 1):

The error means that you defined more than one method mapping the same objective-C method.

Without the source, it is hard to diagnose.

Comment: Good to know, so any ideas how I would track down which one is the issue? can bTouch be run with a debugging switch turned on? I've tried reviewing the bindings and haven't found which one the errors are pointing to.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing the same thing actually, I heavily modified the old "parser" library and am working on doing it now, hopefully dropping it in the public domain.

I'm seeing a similar (and probably related) problem in the ApiDefinition, there is a class AGSGPResultLayer that derives from AGSDynamicLayer. The AGSGPResultLayer overrides a property called Credential among other and since both are defining the same property.

How should over-riden properties be handled in bTouch?  I'm guessing I'm missing something in the syntax.